# program hangs... am I closing the connection/program correctly

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am new to pyodbc.  I have written a simple program.  I think.  The program does not close/quit.  When I run it it hangs until I manually break the program.  It outputs the data. Am I writing it correctly?

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=connect;UID=gog;PWD=humbleb')
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor2.execute("SELECT PTIME, PVALUE FROM HISTORY_TABLE WHERE POINT = 'POINT' AND PTIME> '2017-04-12' AND PTIME<'2017-04-13' AND HISTTYPE='AVG' AND PERIOD=1200")
i=1
sample = cursor2.fetchall()
for rows in sample:
    with open ('C:/directory/record{0}.csv'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(rows)
    i += 1


 cursor2.close()
 conn.close()
```

Comment: It may not answer your question, but it would be better to close your connection before writing to the csv. Otherwise your connection will stay open the entire time

Comment: It may also be a good idea to remove username and password of your database from the question.